# Group presentations and isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-presentation

I am reading Dummit and Foote, and they have only introduced group presentations very informally, so I am worried about the technicalities.

I have to prove that the subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_3)$ generated by 
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\hspace{2cm}
B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is isomorphic to $Q_8$. I know that one presentation of $Q_8$ is
$$Q_8 = \langle -1, i, j, k|(-1)^2=1, i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1 \rangle.$$

Now, if we identify $A$ with $i$, $B$ with $j$, $AB$ with $k$, and $-1$ with $-I$ (where $I$ is the identity matrix, and I can prove that both $I$ and $-I$ are in my subgroup of matrices), then my matrices satisfy the same relations as the ones in my group presentation for $Q_8$.

My question is, am I done? Is this enough to show that the two groups are isomorphic? Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: No, you have proved only that the group $\langle A,B \rangle$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $Q_8$; you haven't proved that they are isomorphic. One approach to completing the proof would be to use the group relations to show that $|Q_8| \le 8$.

Comment: @DerekHolt If I may, I have 3 follow ups to your comment:1) Is the following the best/standard way to prove that $|Q_8| \le 8$: prove by induction on the length of words that any element of $Q_8$ is equal to one of $\pm 1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k$. 2) Don't I also have to show that my subgroup of matrices has order $8$, by exhibiting $8$ different matrices? 3) So I guess it's a theorem that if a group $G$ has a relation $p(g_1, ..., g_n) = q(h_1, ..., h_m)$ and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $G/N$ satisfies the same relation with the identification $g_i \leftrightarrow g_i+N$

Comment: and $h_i \leftrightarrow h_i+N$? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, proving this by induction is the way to go and, yes, you need to know that $\operatorname{SL}_2 \mathbb F_3$ has *at least* eight elements. However, to do this, it suffices to observe that you have four different elements of order $2$, which is not possible in groups with seven elements or less. (As they are $1, C_2, …, C_7$, $C_2 × C_2$ and $S_3$ up to isomorphism and all of them have at most three elements of order $2$.)

Comment: @k.stm Thanks for your comment and answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not quite enough.

What you have done so far is to construct a map $η\colon \{-1, i, j, k\} → \operatorname{SL}_2 \mathbb F_3$ such that $$η(i)^2 = η(j)^2 = η(k)^2 = η(i)η(j)η(k) = η(-1).$$
This is exactly how you start. By the universal property of group presentations there is now exactly one group morphism
$$Q_8 = ⟨-1, i, j, k;~i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = ijk = -1⟩ → \operatorname{SL}_2 \mathbb F_3,$$
extending $η$. So far, so good. Now you need to know that this extension is an isomorphism.

However, this would also be possible if the target was the trivial group, not $\operatorname{SL}_2 \mathbb F_3$. So why should your particular map be an isomorphism onto its image?

To show that this extension is an isomorphism onto its image, you would need to still show that it is injective.

To show it’s injective, you can either try to argue that its kernel is trivial or to argue that $Q_8$ indeed only has at most eight elements, as suggested by Derek Holt. In both cases you need to examine the elements of $Q_8$ as strings in the letters $-1, i, j, k$ and use their relations.

Comment: It is not true that $A$, $B$ and $-1$ generate ${\rm SL}_2({\mathbb F}_3)$, which has order $24$. They generate a subgroup of order $8$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yeah, of course. I was both reading the question sloppily and not thinking for myself. Thanks for the correction!